# When to use 'return' inside a method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
let calculator = {
  sum() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  },

  mul() {
    return this.a * this.b;
  },

  read() {
    this.a = +prompt('a?', 0);
    this.b = +prompt('b?', 0);
  }
};

calculator.read();
alert(calculator.sum());
alert(calculator.mul());
```

So I've been looking at Javascript codes and if you look at the method

```
read() {
  this.a = +prompt('a?', 0);
  this.b = +prompt('b?', 0);
}
```

the read method doesn't return anything to this unlike the `sum`, `mul` methods.
I am guessing this is because the '=' operator already returns the `this.a` and `this.b` to the object. Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're calling `.read()` which is assigning a value to the `a` and `b` properties of the newly created `calculator` object. It doesn't need to return anything with the way you're using it, because the assignment happens within the function due to the `prompt` command.  Then, when you call `.sum()` and `.mul()`, it is using the new property values inside `calculator` to return a value to the `alert` function.

Basically, use a `return` when you need to fill a command with the result of another command; otherwise, you can use assignment like you did here.